# how to add preview time on MediaElement

Tags: jquery, mediaelement.js

Im would like to add time preview(Not preview thumbnail) on my MediaElement on a page but i dont know how! most of the tutorials teach you how to add preview thumbnail but i just want the time and those tutorials which they teach time preview are very complicated to understand. here is what I've done till now:

```
<script>
    $('video').mediaelementplayer({
        features: ['playpause', 'progress', 'current', 'duration', 'tracks', 'volume', 'timerailthumbnails'],
            timeRailThumbnailsSeconds: 5
    });
</script>
```

html code:

```
<video width="320" height="240" poster="poster.jpg" controls="controls" preload="none">
    <source type="video/mp4" src="Videos/cowhand.mp4" />
    <source type="video/webm" src="Videos/cowhand.webm" />
    <source type="video/ogg" src="Videos/cowhand.ogg" />
</video>
```